# What is the error message associated with my plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Goal: 1.Plot
Time vs demand
Time vs OT_ratio
Time vs approdH
all on the same plot.

Details:

`BOD`

```
  Time demand OT_ratio  approxH
1    1    8.3 8.300000 3.060645
2    2   10.3 5.150000 2.695417
3    3   19.0 6.333333 4.256347
4    4   16.0 4.000000 7.997521
5    5   15.6 3.120000 2.599570
6    7   19.8 2.828571 5.678107
```

```
    BOD<_BOD %>% mutate(BOD,OT_ratio=demand/Time )
    BOD<-BOD %>% mutate(approxH=runif(n=6,min=2,max=9))
    ggplot(data=BOD,aes(x=approx,y=OT_ratio))+ 
    +     geom_line(alpha=1/2)
    Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
    Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x = approx. 
    Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you so much!
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Chances are your data is in an odd structure so showing the `dput()` will clear that up.

Comment: Shortest course is to copy the full error message and see many others have contended with this and look for an example much like yours that will help you present a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), as from the error, there are many, and without your `dput`, you're in the best position to say which is most representative.

Comment: Okay, I will update the post with a reproducible example.

Comment: Hopefully, the updated post is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got errors in your post. I'm not sure if that's actually what you have coded in R or if this is just a typo in your post. Mistakes happen, ya know?

When you use a function like `runif()` you should seed it, so that you can at least see if you're getting the right results. Without `seed()` it will change every time.

Either way:

```
# this won't work:
# BOD<_BOD %>% mutate(BOD,OT_ratio=demand/Time )

BOD <- BOD %>% mutate(OT_ratio = demand/Time)

# there was an underscore before BOD and you called the data two times

# here you named the field approxH, but called approx
# BOD<-BOD %>% mutate(approxH=runif(n=6,min=2,max=9))

# set seed for repeatability
set.seed(36)
BOD <- BOD %>% mutate(approx = runif(n = 6, min = 2, max = 9))

# you have a few +'s here that could be from copying the console, though

# ggplot(data=BOD,aes(x=approx,y=OT_ratio))+ 
# +     geom_line(alpha=1/2)

ggplot(data = BOD,
       aes(x = approx,
           y = OT_ratio)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/2)
```

Here's what I've got:
[image]

Comment: Yes, They were typos. The "+" was from copying from the console, the approx should have been approxH,and the  "_" was typing error. Thanks for the corrections. My origional question is how to add another plot over it? add another y-axsis and plot time on x-axis and demand on y-axis

Comment: What is the significance of  36 in the set.seed?

Comment: The number within `set.seed()` is random. It really doesn't matter what number you use; it's there as a control. That is so you can get a random set of numbers the first time but have that same set of numbers if you wanted to rerun the code.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks